# Docker-compose ps not showing any output

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run docker-compose ps and docker-compose logs and neither are showing any output. I was able to run docker-compose up and verified the correct containers are started with docker ps. However docker-compose logs and ps dont show anything

```
> sudo docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose/server1-compose.yml ps
Name   Command   State   Ports 
------------------------------

> sudo docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose/server1-compose.yml logs
Attaching to
```

Both commands are returning intended output. What is wrong here?
docker-compose version: 1.4.2
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

Comment: I responded to your issue on github https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2188#issuecomment-148408311

Answer (score 3):

thanks so @dnephin to posting a response. For completeness here it is:

dnephin-

> " I suspect what's happening here is that the project name is
>   different. The default project name is the basename of a directory, so
>   if you run docker-compose from a different directory you might get a
>   different project name.
>
> You can set it with either -p or COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment
>   variable. If you look at the first part of the container names (before
>   the first underscore) that's the project name.
>
> There are open issues to configure the project name from a file. I
>   think we'll be looking to implement that soon."

Adding the -p switch to my compose command fixed the issue. 
ie: sudo docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose/server1-compose.yml logs -p projectname